# Adding certificate into cacerts file

Tags: java, keystore, filenotfoundexception, access-denied

I wanna add my certificate into cacerts keystore by code, i'm doing it as in snippet below. But i getting FileNotFoundException(access is denied).
I think what that happening because i'm doing that without administrator permissions.
So, how can i fix it?

```
package sertificating;

import java.io.*;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;


/**
 * Created by bugakov on 23.11.2016.
 */
public class Sertificating {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        String certfile = "C:/Users/bugakov/IdeaProjects/school/sertificating/mycert.crt"; 
        String keystorepath=System.getProperties().get("java.home")+"/lib/security/cacerts";
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(keystorepath);
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keystore.load(is, "changeit".toCharArray());
        String alias = "mycert.crt";
        char[] password = "changeit".toCharArray();
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream certstream = fullStream(certfile);
        Certificate certs = cf.generateCertificate(certstream);
        File keystoreFile = new File(keystorepath);
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(keystoreFile);
        keystore.load(in, password);
        in.close();
        keystore.setCertificateEntry(alias, certs);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(keystoreFile);
        keystore.store(out, password);
        out.close();

    }

    private static InputStream fullStream(String fname) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fname);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[dis.available()];
        dis.readFully(bytes);
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        return bais;
    }
}
```

Exception what I getting looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\security\cacerts (Access is denied)
```

at this row

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(keystoreFile);
```

Comment: You need to run your program as administrator, because you're not supposed to be able to inject certificates into the keystore. For example for security reasons.

Comment: The default password for the cacerts file is usually storeIt, but as you say, it seems you dont have administrator permissions to access the JVM path in your operating system (you need write permissions on cacert file). You can open a cmd console running it as administrator, or install the JVM in a user dir and set the JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables pointing to that installation.